# SQL Query to Spring Jpa Specification

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, query-builder, specifications

How I can write this query using JPA Specification and CriteriaBuilder? So, every parent has the same number of maxKids(e.g. 2 kids). Some parent can have more kids but here I want to return every parent that has less kids then in defined maxKids.

```
SELECT p.* FROM Parent AS p LEFT JOIN
(SELECT k.parent_id, COUNT(k.id) AS counted FROM Kids AS k GROUP BY k.parent_id) AS counts
ON p.id = counts.parent_id
WHERE counts.counted IS NULL OR counts.counted < p.maxKids;
```

I have two entities(Parent and Kids)

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
   private Set<Kids> kidsOfParent = new HashSet<>();

   private Integer maxKids;

   //getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class Kids {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn
   private Parent parent;

   private String name;

   //getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we cannot have count and find in the same method of the JpaRepository, so I am doing this in two steps.
In your service layer logic is.

```
List<Parent> parentList = parentRepository.findAll();
parentList.stream().filter(parent-> kidsRepository.countByParent_Id(parent.id)< parent.maxKids).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

ParentRepository.class

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent,Integer> {
}
```

KidsRepository.class

```
@Repository
public interface KidsRepository extends JpaRepository<Kids,Integer> {
   Integer countByParent_Id(Integer id);
}
```